# My twin is a friend indeed (4 letter word)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can be hired if you can afford it 
>   Can be lent for those in need  
>   For work I can’t do myself 
>   My twin is a friend indeed

Who am I?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the answer is

> HAND

Explanation:

I can be hired if you can afford it

> a well-off person can afford a "hired hand"

Can be lent for those in need

> you can "lend a hand" to someone in need

For work I can’t do myself /
My twin is a friend indeed

> If you can't do something with just one hand, using the other hand may help